# Is the group of rational points of an anisotropic absolutely quasi-simple algebraic group over a non-archimedean local field known to be perfect?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose that $G$ is an algebraic group defined over a non-archimedean local field $k$ which is absolutely quasi-simple and anisotropic over $k$. Is it known whether the group $G(k)$ is necessarily perfect?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the book:
Platonov, Rapinchuk, Rowen - Algebraic groups and number theory ?
I seem to recall that they study the structure of the group of points of algebraic groups over various fields of arithmetic interest.

Comment: The *only* examples are central isogenous quotients of ${\rm{SL}}_1(\Delta)$ for central division algebras $\Delta$ over $k$. This is the group of norm-1 units in the unique maximal order of $\Delta$, so it is never perfect (need to argue separately depending on whether or not it accidentally is larger than the 1-units of the order).

Comment: Many thanks, I wonder if you could give me a reference for a proof of the fact that those are the only examples, is it in Platonov's book?

Comment: @Rupert: See 4.5 and 4.6 in Bruhat-Tits III (J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA, Math. 34 (1987), 671--698); in 4.5 they work over a big class of valued fields and get some outer-type A examples too, and in 4.6 they specialize to finite residue field.  They also note that Kneser had handled char. 0 local fields earlier. Hopefully there is a more accessible reference that someone else can provide.